Windows doesn't start after installing Ubuntu (Boot-Repair info included)
This is a newbie question by a dad of a newbie user. My 12-year-old tried to run Ubuntu 24.04 on his Dell/Windows 10 notebook and installed it instead. On top of that he seems to have made some changes in BIOS/UEFI without remembering them. Now my knowledge goes so far as to do a clean Windows reinstall and to search a little bit about the problem, but I have unfortunately no detailed knowledge on Linux or dual boot / partitions. I found a article suggesting using Boot-Repair to gather data which I did.
Can I salvage the Windows operating system and have it boot up again? How could I do this, and could you point me to a resource to help my son and me to then install Ubuntu that it will coexist with Windows? Or should I just start from scratch?
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xmTyzKcFBv/
boot-repair-4ppa2081                                              [20240928_1833]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 2048 
    of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and 
    looks for (,gpt2)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_gpt biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  Grub2's core.img
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sdb: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sdb and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdb: /dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on sda2

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: UHD Graphics 620 from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, noble, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 1.33.0(1.33) from Dell Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot enabled according to mokutil - Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com.
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001
Boot0001* UEFI:  USB, Partition 2   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(12,0)/HD(2,GPT,eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba17-9014c007d874,0xb8b5a0,0x27a0)0000424f


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   hasBIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk identifier: 961F69D8-6122-4C5D-918C-A00AD38C3C4F
     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1   2048      4095      2048     1M BIOS boot
sda2   4096 500115455 500111360 238.5G Linux filesystem
Disk sdb: 28.67 GiB, 30784094208 bytes, 60125184 sectors
Disk identifier: EED3DE8A-ACD3-4541-BA15-9014C007D874
        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sdb1        64 12105119 12105056  5.8G Microsoft basic data
sdb2  12105120 12115263    10144    5M EFI System
sdb3  12115264 12115863      600  300K Microsoft basic data
sdb4  12115968 60123135 48007168 22.9G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:256GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA INTEL SSDSCKKF25:;
1:1049kB:2097kB:1049kB:::bios_grub;
2:2097kB:256GB:256GB:ext4::;
sdb:30.8GB:scsi:512:512:gpt: USB  SanDisk 3.2Gen1:;
1:32.8kB:6198MB:6198MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:6198MB:6203MB:5194kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:6203MB:6203MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:6203MB:30.8GB:24.6GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                
├─sda1                                               7926d262-7f4f-44c7-a0a3-bb36e1c84831                          
└─sda2 ext4     d96ded49-3945-4b0d-b064-7730ef96c525 73ca14d9-03e8-4c4b-aebd-0873875995fd                          
sdb    iso9660  2024-08-27-16-23-26-00                                                    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS amd64 
├─sdb1 iso9660  2024-08-27-16-23-26-00               eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba14-9014c007d874 Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sdb2 vfat     3C53-CAEB                            eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba17-9014c007d874 ESP                      Appended2
├─sdb3                                               eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba16-9014c007d874                          Gap1
└─sdb4 ext4     0fb58fb0-ff21-4aa3-b48b-912843e654a8 9d069f36-a029-46cd-a976-1fed67b70460 writable                 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                               Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2                                                       213G   4% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sdb1                                                          0 100% /cdrom
efivarfs                                                      298.5K  21% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda2                                                     ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdb1                                                     iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8

====================== sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   d96ded49-3945-4b0d-b064-7730ef96c525
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda2/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/d96ded49-3945-4b0d-b064-7730ef96c525 / ext4 defaults 0 1
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0

======================= sda2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 132.202533722 = 141.951389696  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 206.127201080 = 221.327396864  boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
  81.914310455 = 87.954821120   boot/vmlinuz                                   1
  81.914310455 = 87.954821120   boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic                  1
  81.914310455 = 87.954821120   boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
 135.453758240 = 145.442365440  boot/initrd.img                                1
 135.453758240 = 145.442365440  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic               1
 135.453758240 = 145.442365440  boot/initrd.img.old                            1

===================== sda2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18133 Apr  4 10:12 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43202 Apr  4 10:12 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14513 Apr  4 10:12 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   786 Apr  4 10:12 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13120 Apr  4 10:12 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1174 Apr  4 10:12 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   722 Apr  5 11:36 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr  4 10:12 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr  4 10:12 41_custom



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub2 of
sda2 into the MBR of sda.
Grub-efi would not be selected by default because no ESP detected.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s

Confirmation request before suggested repair: __________________________________

The boot of your PC is in EFI mode, but no ESP partition was detected. You may want to retry after creating a ESP partition (FAT32, 100MB~250MB, start of the disk, boot flag).
Are you sure you want to continue anyway?

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________


The boot files of [sda2 (end>100GB)] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as GParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)The boot of your PC is in UEFI mode. You may want to retry after changing it to BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode.


Windows is gone, no NTFS partitions. Best to totally reinstall both Windows & Ubuntu. You have newer UEFI system with UEFI Secure boot on. But Ubuntu is installed in old BIOS boot mode. If you turn UEFI Secure boot off, Ubuntu may boot, but UEFI will not boot old BIOS mode with Secure boot on. Check UEFI settings. How you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS boot mode is how it installs. With UEFI Secure boot on, you have to install in UEFI mode.

@karel I am not sure that is right. As per the first comment I cannot identity a WIN10 partition. I think it has been overwritten.

EFI System Partition (ESP) needs to be 500MB, formatted as FAT32, and the partition needs to have the boot and esp flags set. The Ubuntu installer might require the Manual partitioning option in order to recognize the ESP. The Ubuntu installation USB has a live session option and the Ubuntu live session has a built-in partition editor called GParted. Then you can reinstall Ubuntu, but maybe you want to reinstall Windows instead. If you reinstall Windows then the Windows installer will create whatever bootloader that it needs automatically. First take your time and decide what you want to do.
